# Displaying nmap result gradually as results are found

Tags: nmap, port-scanning

To get `nmap` results, one has to wait for the end of the scan.

How can I force `nmap` to gradually display the newly found hosts and open ports while it is running?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Add this command line switch:

```
-v (Increase verbosity level) .

    Increases the verbosity level, causing Nmap to print more information about 
    the scan in progress. Open ports are shown as they are found and completion 
    time estimates are provided when Nmap thinks a scan will take more than a few 
    minutes. Use it twice or more for even greater verbosity: -vv, or give a 
    verbosity level directly, for example -v3..
```

Source: https://nmap.org/book/man-output.html